# Cannot erase file in $HOME

Tags: filesystems

I have to Backup my whole System, because my HDD is dying.

In $HOME there is a file `.rsync.log` which I cannot erase as my user or as root.

```
LANG=C rm -f /media/alex/3c68c336-bf8d-46f8-bc04-58d3e160f2b1/alex/.rsync.log 
rm: cannot remove '/media/alex/3c68c336-bf8d-46f8-bc04-58d3e160f2b1/alex/.rsync.log': Operation not permitted
```

I ran a filesystemcheck, but that didn't work.

```
LANG=C getfacl /media/alex/3c68c336-bf8d-46f8-bc04-58d3e160f2b1/alex/.rsync.log 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/alex/3c68c336-bf8d-46f8-bc04-58d3e160f2b1/alex/.rsync.log
# owner: alex
# group: alex
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

and

```
lsattr /media/alex/3c68c336-bf8d-46f8-bc04-58d3e160f2b1/alex/.rsync.log 
-----a-------e-- /media/alex/3c68c336-bf8d-46f8-bc04-58d3e160f2b1/alex/.rsync.log
```

Filesystem is ext4.

I need to get rid of this file before I make my backup from $HOME. How can I do so?

Comment: Removing a file has to do with permissions on the base directory, rather than with permissions on the file itself.

Comment: In my case not. I couldn't erase the file when I was running the broken System.  And I have read and write acess there  in my $HOME.  And it was mounted correct. I checked this at once.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, but the file/directory permissions don't usually limit root.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah, I missed the part about running as root.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ lsattr /media/alex/.../.rsync.log 
-----a-------e-- /media/alex/.../.rsync.log
```

The `a` there is the [append only flag](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html), which does work a bit like the immutable flag in that it also prevents removing the file. Also for root:

```
# touch file.txt ; chattr +a file.txt ; lsattr file.txt ; rm file.txt
-----a-------e-- file.txt
rm: cannot remove `file.txt': Operation not permitted
```

> A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be open in append mode for
>          writing.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the
>          CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

`chattr -a /media/alex/.../.rsync.log` as root should get rid of it.